# jquery datepicker highlight weekend days

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a Jquery datepicker for a webapplication, my question is: I want to highlight 2 days at the same time when needed. This is only for the weekend days

When I select Saturday, Sunday must be highlighted (adding a class named: "ui-state-active") too and for Sunday the same, when Sunday selected, Saturday must be highlighted too.

```
beforeShowDay: function(d) {
    var selecteddate =  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
    var day = selecteddate.getDay();

    if (day == 6) { // day 6 = saturday      
       // Now saturday must get the class highlight
       return [true, 'highlight'];
    }
    else if (day == 0){ // day 0 = sunday 
       // Now sunday must get the class highlight
       return[true, 'highlight']; 
    }

}
```

Regards
Dennis

Comment: Have you tried anything yet and what is your current code?

Comment: @JacquesMarais I've searched for the internet and tried the example above I posted, but I can't trigger the other day when one day is selected and can't find anything in common of this.

Comment: And what do you mean with "highlight"? Do you want to set the value to the next day too?

Comment: @JacquesMarais yep, when one day is selected, it has the class "ui-state-active", so then I want that class too on the Saturday or Sunday, based on the selected day.

Comment: Please edit your post to include that information

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `beforeShowDay` event for the datepicker:

> The function takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with
>   [0] equal to true/false indicating whether or not this date is
>   selectable, [1] equal to a CSS class name(s) or '' for the default
>   presentation, and [2] an optional popup tooltip for this date. It is
>   called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

So you need to do something like:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(d) {
        //check if it's Sunday then highlight Saturday and vice versa.
    }
});
```

Comment: See edited question above. This is what I have for now, but I don't know how to set a class for another day.